# ImportError - Python script in Brownie when file is definitely there

Tags: python, brownie

I'm writing a script in Python to deploy the smart contract lottery (from the older Brownie/Python course from freecodecamp). I am only trying to deploy on development, so I have saved all the necessary mock contracts in the contracts folder (MockV3Aggregator, VRFCoordinatorMock, LinkTokenInterface, etc). But when I run the script I get the error that "LinkTokenInterface" and "VRFConsumerBase" cannot be found in the contracts folder even though they are definitely there. See screenshot below.

One thing I was wondering is I also imported the chainlink-brownie-contracts into a lib folder, so there are dupes of these contracts in the lib folder. When I say "from brownie import LinkTokenInterface" would there be a collision if there were two files names LinkTokenInterface, one in contracts and one in lib? I also tried from contracts import LinkTokenInterface and that also gets the same error.

I also tried to open the **init**.py file but it didn't help

[image: Here is the error I am getting and my script]